# Parent to Child hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

i just want to ask if is there any way to do this using only css :hover or i should use jquery? I'm making a static website and just to refresh myself from backend :)

now here's my problem

```
<button class="btn" id="landingButton">
    <div class="row row-for-button">
        <div class="col-10">
            <strong>View my work</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2" id="arrow-right">
            <ion-icon name="arrow-round-forward"></ion-icon>
        </div>
    </div>
</button>
```

I have here a button. whenever i made the arrow-right rotate whenever i hover it. and the button changes color also when hovered . the problem is how can i make the arrow hovered to when i hover the button? because it is more like it don't rotate when i only hovered the button, i need to hover the arrow itself.

here's my css code

```
     #landingButton {
         font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
         border: solid 2px #e31b6d;
         color: #e31b6d;
         padding: 8px 20px;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
     }

     #arrow-right {
        padding-left: 0px !important;
        padding-top: 2px !important;
    }

   ion-icon {
       transition: all 0.4s ease;
   }

   ion-icon:hover {
       transform: rotateZ(90deg);
   }

   #landingButton:hover {
       background-color: #e31b6d;
       color: white; 
   }
```

Is there any way i could make it work using css or i should use jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I make the arrow rotate when I hover the button?

```
#landingButton:hover ion-icon {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

Comment: ^ agreeing with this answer. Don't forget to consider when a user focuses the button as well for accessibility:

"#landingButton:hover ion-icon, #landingButton:focus ion-icon"

Happy Coding!